# Implementing python list and Binary search tree

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on making a index for a text file. index will be an list of every word and symbols like(~!@#$%^&*()_-{}:"<>?/.,';[]1234567890|) and counting the number of times each token occurred in the text file. printing all this in an ascending ASCII value order.

I am going to read a .txt file and split the words and special characters and store it in a list. Can any one throw me idea on how to use binary search in this case.

Comment: it looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/137096). Start with `collections.Counter()`, to count frequencies of every word, symbol.

Answer (score 0):

If your lookup is small (say, up to 1000 records), then you can use a dict; you can either `pickle()` it, or write it out to a text file. Overhead (for this size) is fairly small anyway.

If your look-up table is bigger, or there are a small number of lookups per run, I would suggest using a key/value database (e.g. dbm).

If it is too complex to use a dbm, use a SQL (e.g. sqlite3, MySQL, Postgres) or NoSQL database. Depending on your application, you can get a huge benefit from the extra features these provide.

In either case, all the hard work is done for you, much better than you can expect to do it yourself. These formats are all standard, so you will get simple-to-use tools to read the data.